# Getting 'DateTime.ToString()' to output the same string as an XML serialization of a 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

Is there a standard `DateTime` format for use in C# that can be used with the `ToString` method that will produce the same format that is produced when you serialize a `DateTime` to XML?

For example: `2013-03-20T13:32:45.5316112Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.ToString("o") seemed to do the trick

Comment: That will lack the "z" at the end though, I think.

Comment: Z was there using that parameter

Comment: Ah interesting - the [MSDN documentation's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) doesn't have it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson At the link you provided that now resolves to .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5, the UTC `DateTime` formatting example now includes `Z` in the output: `2009-06-15T13:45:30` (`DateTimeKind.Utc`) --> `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z`.

Comment: Not quite though: DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-02T12:35:04.140625"); XMLSerialization makes <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dateTime>2016-08-02T12:35:04.140625</dateTime> out of it while t1.ToString("o") results in "2016-08-02T12:35:04.1406250". It is only a minor difference, but I'm currently looking for string-equality of the result, so just wanted to raise this minor difference.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to be specific:

```
dateTime.ToString(“yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ”);
```

You have to be careful about using the right time zone. [See here for more details.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/07/387677.aspx)

Comment: see my comment for @user1450877's answer. This is true here also. Seems like serialization works slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalFull

The format you want is:

```
myDate.ToString("u");
```

Example:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u"));
// Displays 2008-04-10 13:30:00Z
```

However, this is not quite what you're after (though probably would still work), therefore you may have to use a custom format:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"));
// Displays 2008-04-10T13:30:00.000000Z
```

Comment: It's close, but it's using a space to separate the time from the date, rather than `T`.

Comment: Edited to also show the T, remember - you need to cast your date to UTC first!